# pass and display Countdowntimer value to other activities

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a countdowntimer that I want to display on a TextView, it works fine in the first activity where it starts. But I can't get to pass the remained time to the next activity and display it. I tried to pass it with 'putExtra' but when I display it, I just get the remained time and its stuck on it while the countdowntimer is still running background. Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Resume the remaining time in the new Activity. Or keep listening with a listener.

Comment: have you tried to start and save the remaining time value in the ```View Model```? I think you can use ```View Model``` to store the timer value

Comment: Hi @JabalLogian - I'm doing that just now in a shared ViewModel, but I move to another activity with a different ViewModel and it doesn't seem to keep running.